# API design suggestion

Tags: java, api-design, abstraction

I am developing an API (library) for servers (imagine a simple server that receives a request and writes a response back on the connection).

I have a situation where I have 3 different frameworks (third party libraries). All of these provide a way to handle requests, but in their own way. Imagine the following are the interfaces to each lib:

**lib A**

```
public class AHandler implements AHandler {

  public Response handle(Request req){
   // ..
  }
}
```

**lib B**

```
public class BHandler extends SomeHandler {

  public BResponse handle(BRequest req){
   // ..
  }
}
```

**lib C**

```
@Handler
public class BHandler {
  @HandlerMethod
  public void handle(CRequest req, CResponse res){
   // ..
  }
}
```

I want to create an API that abstracts out the `handle()` method into some uniform way. Since A, B and C are third party, I don't have a way to modify them.

**Facts:**

- the user can have one or more of such Handlers per server;
- I can't modify the source of the third party libs and I don't want to control their releases.

What is the best way to go about API designing that can provide an uniform interface for all the three libs?

Comment: Why it is too broad!! It has clear specific answer of interface modeling.

Comment: Design advice is not what we do here. [softwareengineering.se] and [codereview.se] both have topics that can permit questions that are less narrowly focused on the specific -- but read their individual rules; I'm not asserting via this comment that the question at hand would be permitted on either. See [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777), and [What goes on Software Engineering? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7182)

Comment: See also [Where can I ask a question about design patterns?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131940/where-can-i-ask-a-question-about-design-patterns) on [meta.se]. George Stocker's answer to [Are questions about design patterns at fault for being “primarily opinion-based”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278063/14122) is also a good one, insofar as it explains some of the "why" of the question's reception.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve the desired result using a combination of **facade** and **adapters**.

```
// defines the uniform interface exposed to API clients
interface Facade {
    void handleRequest(Request request, Response response)
}

// defines the uniform interface each handler will have to expose
interface Adapter {
    void handleRequest(Request request, Response response)
}

// takes a concrete adapter as argument and delegates to it for the concrete handle logic implementation
class ConcreteFacade implements Facade{

    private Adapter adapter;

    public ConcreteFacade(Adapter adapter){
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    public void handleRequest(Request request, Response response){
        adaper.handleRequest(request, response);
    }

}

// one concrete adapter for each library
class ConcreteAdapter implements Adapter {

    private AHandler handler; 

    public ConcreteAdapter(AHandler handler){
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void handleRequest(Request request, Response response) {
        //delegate to handler
    }

}
```